# Nuance Loquendo VoiceExperienceClassic txt file as input

Tags: text-to-speech

I have installed a nuance loqeundo service in my server, i can make my .wav files  in a language if a manually make the input of the text with:

`sudo opt/Loquendo/LTTs7/bin/VoiceExperienceClassic -v Mihai` ...

and everything ok, but when I try to make the input as a txt file i get a "Licensing error prevents from reading the prompt".

my licensing is with friendcode and my first line in the txt file is my friend code. but the error keep showing.

Thanks in advice,

Comment: solution: finally i get it opt/Loquendo/LTTs7/bin/VoiceExperienceClassic -v Mihai </direction/input/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opt/Loquendo/LTTs7/bin/VoiceExperienceClassic -v Mihai </direction/input/file
```